# ¿Como limitar una entrada(compra) por usuario?

Tags: php, mysql

Este código es el action de un formulario de compras, quiero que solo un usuario pueda registrar una compra. Aquí en el código si no has comprado nada, tu ID no estará en la tabla boletos por lo que podrás agregar la información, sin embargo si tu ID ya fue agregada se supone que debería devolverte al index, sin embargo me encuentro con que el mismo usuario puede seguir agregando compras y tener múltiples compras con su mismo ID y no entiendo que esta pasando, no me da un error o algo.

```
 session_start (); 
  include 'dbh.inc.php';

$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

////Valores para el formulario
$sala = $_POST ['cbmboxsala1'];
$horario = $_POST ['cbmboxhorario1'];
$asiento = $_POST ['cbmboxasiento1'];

if ( isset($_POST['btncomprar']) ) 

{

$sql = "SELECT * FROM boleto WHERE user_id = '$userid'";  
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  

{

$sql = "UPDATE  users SET sala = '$sala', horario = '$horario', asiento = '$asiento' WHERE user_id = '$userid'";
                mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);                     
                header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");                            
                exit ();
}

else 
{
    header("Location: ../index.php?factura=yatienesuna");
}


 }

else

 {
  echo 'error';
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: Intenta quitar el `!` en `if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`

Comment: Fue una de las cosas que intente también, pero nada, sigue registrando la compra del boleto.

Comment: Realiza un echo a $userid antes del select a tu base de datos. Lo más probable es que la variable siempre está vacia y por eso hagas lo que hagas con la lógica de tu código siempre pasa a la opción de tu update en vez de a tu msj de que ya posee una. Intenta y notifica si se resolvió por favor

Comment: <?php
session_start (); 
include 'dbh.inc.php';
//include 'login.inc.php'; 

$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

 //Valores para el formulario
 $sala = $_POST ['cbmboxsala1'];
 $horario = $_POST ['cbmboxhorario1'];
 $asiento = $_POST ['cbmboxasiento1'];

if ( isset($_POST['btncomprar']) ) 

{
 echo $userid;

}

else 

{
 echo 'error';
}
?>

---
elimine el código para que solo me diera el echo de la variable en caso de presionar el boton compra Y AUN ASÍ, registra en la base de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un error conceptual. La consulta "SELECT * FROM boleto WHERE user_id = '$userid'" no retorna false si no lo encuentra, retorna un array vacío. Para que te retorne false la consulta debe ser "errónea".
Revisar la función: [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias, no tenia idea ! ahora estoy buscando otra manera de limitar la compra.

Comment: La función mysqli_num_rows te permite saber el número de resultados de la consulta. Haciendo $total = mysqli_num_rows($result); podrías obtener el número de registros encontrados, si es mayor o igual a 1 es que ya existe.

Comment: Grande, capo ! estudie el mysqli_num_rows para ver como funcionaba y tras una hora de ensayo y error lo logre, gracias !